# Text selection cross-browser bugs and differences with ascender & tittle rendering

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

I'm using [PMN Caecilia](https://www.linotype.com/5517740/pmn-caecilia-family.html) on a website but cannot get consistent text selection behavior cross-browser. Below is the custom CSS to change the text selection background and font color.

```
::selection {
    background-color: #002d5b;
    color: white;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #002d5b;
    color: white;
}
```

The biggest problem is with Google Chrome (62.0.3202.94). Below are some screenshots:

Normal rendering (without text selection):
[image: without text selection]

Rendering bug during text selection; affects characters in the same text block (see "l" in "lots")

[image: during text selection]

Firefox (57.0.1):

[image: firefox text selection]

Safari (11.0.1):

[image]

In general, are these CSS properties that allow for more control over font rendering? I've tried adjusting properties line `line-height` to 1 and above, along with `line-height-step`, `height`, `text-size-adjust`, and a few others. It doesn't seem like this behavior is controllable.